# Text/Links background should be transparent over a gradient background but is in white

Tags: html, css

I have a small problem. I'm starting to devise a new site for myself, www.dvpwebdesign.com. I'm currently just using html and css on it. The problem i have is IE, my intro page has a repeated gradient background, with links/text over it. All works fine on Safari, Firefox, but not the dreaded IE, which shows a white background behind the text. The rest of the screen has the gradient background correctly. I know you are supposed to use background-color:none, which i did do. I also tried background-color:transparent, all to no avail. If anyone can help i'd be very appreciative? Below is the CSS, you can get the html from the site which is live, thanks in advance:

```
body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
background-color: none;
width:1000px;
background-image: url(gradient4.jpg);
background-repeat: repeat-x;
}



 #menu a{
    color:#a0a0a0;
    font-weight:normal;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size:14px;
    margin-left:10px;
    margin-top:-35px;
    font-family: Skia;


    }
#menu a span.two{
    color:#33ccff;
    cursor:pointer;
        font-size:14px;
        font-weight:500px;
    font-family: Skia;

}

     #menutwo a{
    color:#9966ff;
    font-weight:normal;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size:12px;
    margin-left:10px;
    margin-top:-35px;
    font-family: Skia;

}
#menutwo a span.two{
    color:#660099;
    cursor:pointer;
        font-size:12px;
    font-family: Skia;

}
#menuthree a{
    color:#c8c8c8;
    font-weight:normal;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size:80px;
    font-family: Skia;


    }
#menuthree a span.two{
    color:#33ccff;
    cursor:pointer;
        font-size:80px;
    font-family: Skia;

}

     #menufour a{
    color:#b8b8b8;
    font-weight:normal;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size:42px;
    font-family: Skia;


}
#menufour a span.two{
    color:#339999;
    cursor:pointer;
        font-size:42px;
    font-family: Skia;
}

     #menufive a{
    color:#a8a8a8;
    font-weight:normal;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size:22px;
    font-family: Skia;


}
#menufive a span.two{
    color:#0066ff;
    cursor:pointer;
        font-size:22px;
    font-family: Skia;
}



ul#menu {
width : 1000px;
list-style-type : none;
position : relative;
margin-top:20px;
margin-right:230px;
float: right;
display:inline;
    font-family: Skia;

letter-spacing: 1px;
}

#menu li {float: right;                
display:inline;}

ul#menutwo {
width : 1000px;
letter-spacing: 1px;
margin-top:-10px;
margin-bottom:20px;
list-style-type : none;
position : relative;
float: right;
display:inline;
font-size:24px;
    font-family: Skia;
margin-right:180px;
}

#menutwo li {float: right;                
display:inline;}

ul#menuthree {
width : 1000px;
letter-spacing: 1px;
list-style-type : none;
position : relative;
float: left;
display:inline;
    font-family: Skia;

top: 300px;
}

#menuthree li {float: left;                
display:inline;}

ul#menufour {
width : 1000px;
letter-spacing: 1px;
list-style-type : none;
position : relative;
float: left;
display:inline;
    font-family: Skia;

top: 320px;

}

#menufour li {float: left;                
display:inline;}

ul#menufive {
width : 1000px;
letter-spacing: 1px;
list-style-type : none;
position : relative;
float: left;
display:inline;
    font-family: Skia;

top: 340px;

}

#menufive li {float: left;                
display:inline;}
```

Comment: And you are aware, btw, that the `Skia` font will not show up on any computer but yours (and the few others it may be installed on)?

Comment: Sorry i forgot to mention there is some Jquery for the links. Everything works fine on Safari, Firefox, and Opera, just not IE.

Comment: Live link: www.dvpwebdesign.com

Comment: Hi Pekka, yes i know the Skia font will change to a default font on certain browsers. I'm just experimenting at the moment.

Comment: It indeed shows up white in IE6. Are you sure you are applying the `background-color: transparent` to the right element? Have you tried giving it to the `a` and the `span` s inside?

Answer (score 1):

Some of your jQuery shenanigans must be applying the background colour as an inline style.

This is what I get in IE 8's developer tools for the spans:

```
filter: alpha(opacity=100); ZOOM: 1; background: #fff;
```

**Update:** here it is. In `fadelinks.js`

```
var bgcolor = "#fff";   // unfortunately we have to set bg color because of that freakin' IE *!$%#!!?!?%$! 
                        //please use the same background color in your links as it is in your document.
```

Comment: Oh right, i'd never have found that. Can i ask how you managed to find this so quickly?

Comment: @DVP I used the developer tools in IE8 (press F12, and navigate through the element tree to the link element) to find out there was an inline style set. It wasn't set in the HTML source, so it must have been added by a script. So, check out all the JavaScript. `fadelinks.js` was an obvious suspect as it's designed to be meddling with links anyway, so I opened it and saw the `#fff`.

Comment: Cheers Pekka, i'll try it out, have a nice weekend.

Comment: Trouble is, what do i change the fadelinks.js property for the background color to as i'm using a gradient background rather than a web color background? I tried selecting 'none' instead but this stops all the link colors working and just show in gray.

Comment: @DVP try `transparent`. If that doesn't work, you may have a problem, because probably that's the reason why there is a background colour explicitly set....

Comment: No change, so it looks like unless you have a white background this fadelinks.js is pretty useless, thats a shame. Thanks once again Pekka.